# Setting umask for sshfs mount

Tags: file-permissions, sshfs, umask

If I mount the sshfs server with no umask, i get `-rw-rw-r--` on new created files. If I try and open a php file on the server on my browser, i get this error:

```
Incorrect file/directory permissions: Above 755.
In order files to be processed by the webserver, their permissions have to be equal or below 755.
```

So I tried with `umask=0022`: the new created files have `-rwxr-xr-x`. These permissions are fine, as the error above does not appear anymore. However, I can't understand why the new files are set as executables...

Could you please explain? Many thanks...

Answer (score 6):

From `sshfs` manual:

```
   -o umask=M
          set file permissions (octal)
```

Note the manual mentions the option name is `umask`. So it is not the same values you would use in `chmod`, where `7` means `rwx` (binary `111`). Instead, `umask` is a *mask*, as the name says.

For `fuse`, this mask is used as an inversion of the desired permission.

Then, from http://wiki.gilug.org/index.php/How_to_mount_SFTP_accesses#General_working_of_umask, we get the following:

> [umask i]s a template-mask. Is as a chmod inverse, because is used for shading the permissions to be set when creating files and directories. As higher is the octal value, more restrictive (at binary level a bit 1 shades an attribute and a bit 0 allows it).

```
0 allows rwX
1 allows rw-
2 allows r-X
3 allows r--
4 allows -wX
5 allows -w-
6 allows --X
7 allows ---
```

So, if you supply `0022`, the permission will go as follows:

1. AND with `0777` (see *umask* man page) to consider only "user", "group" and "others" permissions (i.e. discard first part of the mask).

`000 000 010 010 -> 0022`

`AND`

`000 111 111 111 -> 0777`

`=`

`000 000 010 010 -> 0022`

2. Invert the three permissions.

`000 010 010 -> 022`

becomes

`111 101 101 -> 755`

If you don't want the files to be executable, but want them to be readable and writable (`chmod 666`), you should set `umask` to:

```
110 110 110 = 666 <- chmod value
001 001 001 = 111 <- umask value
```

Comment: If setting non-executable umask bit it won't be possible to list directories.

Comment: See comment on https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/290212 
 
The umask option for sshfs goes down to the underlying fuse layer where it's handled wrongly. afaict the advice is to avoid it. – Ralph Rönnquist Jun 17 '16 at 7:56

Comment: This is wrong or confusing. The mask is FIRST inverted, and then AND is applied to find the resulting permissions. Your example happens to yield the same result because your starting value is 777 and X AND 1 = X. But the correct function is different: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask#How_the_mask_is_applied

Answer (score 3):

The `umask` sshfs option only deals with how the remote files appear to you on your local system, this shed some light on the issue for me: [serverfault.com/q/228396](https://serverfault.com/questions/228396/how-to-setup-sshs-umask-for-all-type-of-connections), a desired umask of 0002 for remotely created files and folders was achieved with:

Lines appended to `/etc/pam.d/sshd` on the remote system:

```
# Setting UMASK for all ssh based connections (ssh, sftp, scp)
session    optional     pam_umask.so umask=0002
```

This one has been a long-running issue for me, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

In fuse drivers the `umask` option does not work intuitively.

- It doesn't mask existing permissions. Instead it sets the permissions to its inverse.
- It only applies when reading. For `sshfs` new files and folders have their permissions set according to the `sshd` config on the remote host.

And the combination of the two means there's no way to see what the remote permissions actually are if `umask` is set.

Some drivers offer separate `fmask`/`dmask` options to avoid making everything executable, but `sshfs` is not one of them. If you want no files to be executable then the `noexec` will work (but not be reflected in the permissions). If some files should be executable and others not, then it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Some filesystems allows to set masks separately for directories and files with `dmask` and `umask`, which would allow you to disable executable bit for files. I'm not sure if sshfs offers it, others have asked for it -> https://superuser.com/questions/1020582/fuse-file-system-fmask-and-dmask.

You can set `noexec` option for whole filesystem if you don't want any user to execute any files.

Comment: Sadly, fuse/sshfs does not support dmask nor fmask.